# Tic-Tac-Toe Backend for Commercial Use

Tags: python, python-3.x, tic-tac-toe, modules

I've been working on a tic-tac-toe backend for an interactive commercial-use display, and was wondering if I could get some feedback on it?

```py
#tttcore.py ~ Manages game state, checks win condition, etc.
from enum import Enum
from typing import Optional, Any, Iterable
from copy import deepcopy as copy

class OutOfBoundsError(IndexError): pass
class SpaceOccupied(IndexError): pass

class GameEnd(Exception): pass
class XWin(GameEnd): pass
class OWin(GameEnd): pass
class CatsGame(GameEnd): pass

class TTTPlayer(Enum):
    X = 0
    O = 1

class TicTacToeCore:
    def __init__(self, width: int = 3, *, board = None):
        # Note: width arg is ignored when a board is supplied
        if board:
            self.width = len(board)
            self.board = board
        else:
            self.width = width
            self.board = [[None for _ in range(self.width)]
                          for _ in range(self.width)]
        
    def move(self, x: int, y: int, player: TTTPlayer):
        # Note: Coords are 0-indexed
        if not isinstance(x, int):
            raise TypeError(f"x-coord must be int, got {x.__class__}")
        if not isinstance(y, int):
            raise TypeError(f"y-coord must be int, got {y.__class__}")
        if not isinstance(player, TTTPlayer):
            raise TypeError(f"player must be TTTPlayer, got {player.__class__}")
        
        if x < 0 or x >= self.width:
            raise OutOfBoundsError(f"x-coord must be between 0 and {self.width-1}, inclusive, got {x} instead")
        if y < 0 or y >= self.width:
            raise OutOfBoundsError(f"y-coord must be between 0 and {self.width-1}, inclusive, got {y} instead")
        
        if self.board[x][y]:
            raise SpaceOccupied(f"You know you're supposed to catch this exception, right? How we got here: Space ({x}, {y}) is occupied by {self.board[x][y]}.")
        self.board[x][y] = player
        
        self._check_win(player)
        
        return True
    
    def _check_win(self, player: TTTPlayer):
        def check(row: Iterable[Optional[TTTPlayer]]):
            if all(space == player for space in row):
                if player == TTTPlayer.X:
                    raise XWin()
                else:
                    raise OWin()
        
        for row in self.board:
            check(row)
        for col in zip(*self.board):
            check(col)
        for diag in ([self.board[x][x] for x in range(self.width)],
                     [self.board[x][self.width-x-1] for x in range(self.width)]):
            check(diag)
        
        if not any(None in row for row in self.board):
            raise CatsGame()
    
    def board_repr(self, prefix=" "):
        mapping = {None: "-", TTTPlayer.X: "X", TTTPlayer.O: "O"}
        
        board_copy = copy(self.board)
        for i, row in enumerate(board_copy):
            row.insert(0, str(i))
        board_copy.insert(0, [" ", *map(str, range(self.width))])
        
        return prefix + ("\n" + prefix).join((" ".join(mapping.get(player, player)
                                                       for player in row))
                                             for row in board_copy)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"TicTacToeCore(width={self.width!r}, board={self.board!r})"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import ttt_terminal
```

```py
#basictttgame.py ~ an extensible frontend demo for the backend
from tttcore import *

from pygame import mixer as audio

import os

ASSETS_FOLDER = "assets"
AUDIO_FOLDER = os.path.join(ASSETS_FOLDER, "audio")
SFX_FOLDER = os.path.join(AUDIO_FOLDER, "sfx")

def cls():
    os.system('cls' if os.name=='nt' else 'clear')

class Colors:
    """Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/287944/14212394"""
    HEADER = '\033[95m'
    OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
    OKCYAN = '\033[96m'
    OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
    WARNING = '\033[93m'
    FAIL = '\033[91m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'

def basic_ttt_game(in_, restart):
    audio.init()
    audio.music.load(os.path.join(AUDIO_FOLDER, "bg.mp3"))
    audio.music.set_volume(0.1)
    button_sfx = audio.Sound(os.path.join(SFX_FOLDER, "button.wav"))
    error_sfx = audio.Sound(os.path.join(SFX_FOLDER, "error.wav"))
    audio.music.play(-1)

    while True:
        player = TTTPlayer.X
        game = TicTacToeCore()
        
        try:
            while True:
                cls()
                print(Colors.BOLD + "\n\n\n\tTicTacToe in the Terminal" + Colors.ENDC)
                print("\n\tBoard:")
                print(game.board_repr("\t"))
                print(f"\n\t{player.name} is up!")
                
                while True:
                    try:
                        x, y = map(int, in_())
                        game.move(y, x, player)
                        button_sfx.play()
                        break
                    
                    except ValueError:
                        print(Colors.WARNING + "\tThat's not a number! >:(\n" + Colors.ENDC)
                        error_sfx.play()
                        
                    except OutOfBoundsError:
                        print(Colors.WARNING + "\tThose coordinates don't work! >:(\n" + Colors.ENDC)
                        error_sfx.play()
                        
                    except SpaceOccupied:
                        print(Colors.WARNING + "\tSomeone's already there! >:(\n" + Colors.ENDC)
                        error_sfx.play()
                
                player = TTTPlayer.O if player == TTTPlayer.X else TTTPlayer.X
                
        except GameEnd as e:
            cls()
            button_sfx.play()
            print(Colors.BOLD + "\n\n\n\tTicTacToe in the Terminal" + Colors.ENDC)
            print("\n\tBoard:")
            print(game.board_repr("\t"))

            if type(e) == XWin:
                print(Colors.BOLD + Colors.OKGREEN + "\n\tX Wins!\n" + Colors.ENDC)
            elif type(e) == OWin:
                print(Colors.BOLD + Colors.OKGREEN + "\n\tO Wins!\n" + Colors.ENDC)
            else:
                print(Colors.BOLD + Colors.FAIL + "\n\tCat's Game!\n" + Colors.ENDC)
            print("\tHit any button to restart!")
            restart()
```

```py
#ttt_terminal.py ~ a simple terminal-based test of the backend using the above script
from basictttgame import *

basic_ttt_game(lambda: input("\tX-Coordinate Of Move: "), input("\tY-Coordinate Of Move: "))
```